# Deflate/Unzip data from byte string

Tags: python-3.x, string, byte, gzip, deflate

I have a binary file, without extension (juste filename). It contains several images. The xml header contains several informations about each images or stacks of images.

For example, the first stack of images has informations like `totalBytes=7029545`, and `compress=Deflated`. However, other stacks contains `compress=None`, and I managed to read them without problem.

But for the first, from what I understand, I can't read them unless I decompress the "data". The data from the first stack are stored in a "string", which is of class "`bytes`" (resulting from `type( my_first_stack_data )` ).

I tried several methods to uncompress the data, from zlib, gzip, lzma. But none works. I even tried zlib for all possible wbits values (from -15 to 48)...

The begining of the data looks like this ( `from my_first_stack_data[:100]` ) :

```
b'\x00x\x9c\xec\xbdu\xdcW\xc5\x13?:3\x1b\xe7\xd3\xf1t\xc2CwwwHKJIwHw#JK\x87\x94\x88t\xa3\xa4 \x88  \x88 \x824JI\xa7\x02\xa2\xe2\xdd=\x9f\xcf\x13\xa2\xde\xfb\xba\x7f\xfc|\xbe\x97s\xc7\xd7sj\xf7\x1c?\xfbffgvvv\x16\xe0\x7f\x93H\xfdE\xc1ZxS\x9d+@w\xf3\x19\x9a'
```

And for example, the `gzip.decompress` method gives me the exception : `OSError: Not a gzipped file (b'\x00x')`

How could I read/uncompress that "bytes" string (and not the whole file which also contains uncompressed data successfully read)? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think your data is missing the GZIP header of three bytes which specifies the compression method.  From what I tested, you might have luck with adding a prefix of `'\x1F\x8B\x08'` and then pass that into `gzip.decompress()`.

With the shortened data you provided this still leads to a `zlib.error` exception with message `Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid block type`, but maybe that's an effect of the shortening and if you use the original data instead, it might work.

```
import gzip

decompressed = gzip.decompress(bytes([ 0x1F, 0x8B, 0x08 ]) + original_bytes)
```